# Fragments ConstraintLayout is cut of in FrameLayout of activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-constraintlayout, android-framelayout

I have an activity `LoginActivity` and a fragment `SignupSocialFragment`.
The fragment is loaded inside of the `FrameLayout` inside the activity.

The problem is, that the `LinearLayout` (`social_login_footer`) in fragment which is constrained to the bottom of its parent is cut of when the fragment is displayed in the activity.
When I add padding/margin to the `social_login_footer`I can shift it into view but this does not work reliable.
Can anyone help with why the bottom part is cut of?
Shouldnt the `ConstraintLayout` match the height of its parent `FrameLayout`.

### Code

`activity_login.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/login_constraint"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorBlack"
    tools:context=".ui.login.LoginActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_constraint_2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
            android:id="@+id/login_lottie_animation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
            app:lottie_fileName="background_rotation.json"
            app:lottie_loop="true" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/login_logo"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.050000012"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo_white" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/login_logo_subtitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="@string/slogan"
        android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:translationY="-10dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/login_logo"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/login_logo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/login_logo" />


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/login_content"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login_logo_subtitle"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`fragment_login_social.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#300000CC "
    android:paddingStart="32dp"
    android:paddingEnd="32dp"
    tools:context=".ui.login.SignupSocialFragment">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/login_social_text"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="32dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_light"
        android:text="@string/login_subtitle"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/social_login_email"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/social_login_email"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/email_signup_btn"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/social_login_facebook"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login_social_text" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/social_login_facebook"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:icon="@drawable/facebook_logo"
        app:iconGravity="textStart"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/social_login_google"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/social_login_email" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/social_login_google"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/social_login_facebook">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/social_login_google_txt"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:text="@string/google_signup_btn"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/social_login_google_logo"
            android:layout_width="24dp"
            android:layout_height="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/googleg_standard_color_18"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/social_login_google_txt"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/social_login_member"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:text="@string/already_member"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/social_login_google" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/social_login_footer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/login_version"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_version"
            android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/login_policy"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            android:text="@string/privacy_link"
            android:textSize="12sp" />

    </LinearLayout>


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

### Layout blueprints

[image: activity_login.xml]
[image: fragment_login_social.xml]

### Rendered on Nexus 5X API 28

[image]

Comment: where exactly you want to show your linear layout ?

Comment: There where it is in the blueprint.

Comment: I have tried your code it's working fine on my device.

Comment: Is it working on all devices or just one specific? It should also work without the paddingbottom of constraint layout. Ive removed it now in the code samples. So the linear layout should stick to the bottom and has a margin. But the layout itself normally has no vertical padding. When I have a large screen it is displayed.

Comment: I have checked on only one device i.e pixel 2 phone and it's working fine there.

Comment: @Umair ive removed the `paddingBottom` in `fragment_login_social.xml` and added a screenshot of what is rendered in the emulator.

Comment: Ok let me test it further. if it works as expected or not.

Comment: it's working as expected now I have tested it on nexus, and on honor devices.

Answer (score 1):

After wasting some hours of my precious lifetime I have finally found it.

The problem is caused by the `ImageView`s `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` attribute.

After removing it everything works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to `fragment_login_social.xml` first child view